# JSDoc for a method that doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to fix JSDoc for my methods right now. And I'm confused of what I should write for it as the method doesn't return anything but call another method depending on if/else code.

```
methodOne () {
  if (something) {
    this.runMethod()
  } else {
    this.runAnotherMethod()
  }
}
```

Comment: `@returns <void>`?

Comment: Uh, you just don't have an `@return`? I am not sure what you're trying to document here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
methodOne(): void {
  if (something) {
    this.runMethod()
  } else {
    this.runAnotherMethod()
  }
}
```